# Writing a loop as an mathematical Equation

Tags: math

For Documentation purposes I need to write a simple loop as a mathematical equation. But there is one thing I can't wrap my head around.

```
j = 1;
for(i = N; i > 1; --i){
    j = 2*j+1;
}
scale = 1/j;
```

Sadly I can't write it as a simple ^N or at least I can't find the expression because of the +1. Do you know a good mathematical expression?

Comment: What is the initial value of `j`?

Comment: oh, forgot that: j = 1

Comment: Lastly, why is the loop written backwards? It merely obfuscates.

Comment: @Bathsheba some other calls in this loop rely on being 'counted down'. For this equation however its indifferent. As long it gets called N-1 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all far too obfuscated.

Let's rewrite to

```
j = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i){
   j = 2 * j + 1;
}
```

Then you can see that this loop can be rewritten as

j = 2<sup>N</sup> - 1

and you can hence change not only the documentation, *but* the code too.

Comment: Ha! Now I see it, too. Thanks a lot. Don't know why I wasn't able to see it prior.

Comment: I could only see it once I simplified it a little.